# Clicking on search button from SearchView, changes ActionBar style

Tags: android, searchview

I am using `SearchView` to provide search in an application. Everything works fine, except when I'm in the searchable activity and click on the search button.

This is when opening the `SearchableActivity` (ok):

[image]

This is what happens if I click on the search button to initiate a new search (not ok):
[image]

As you can see the style of the ActionBar changes (both action bar and suggestion dropdown), it looks like when the action mode is enabled, and I don't have idea why this is happening.

And now I click back or up button, the ActionBar is reset to initial style (what should I get when clicking on the search button):

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because in the `SearchableActivity` I was intercepting the search button and calling `onSearchRequested()`:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
 }
```

There's no need for `onOptionsItemSelected()` to be overrided, deleteting this piece of code solved the issue.